# UI Overlay Over a Foreign Application

Tags: objective-c, overlay

So I've studied the code in FunkyOverlayWindow, an example given on the Mac Developer Library.

However now I wanted to make an overlay for a specific application; I specifically had in mind a game that I wanted to make an interactive overlay for, something like an overlayed menu at the top. How would I identify and call upon a specific window that's opened?

Thanks!